# Click to dial a phone number from MS access to MS teams

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink

I'm new to MS access but have a lot of experience with excel. I'm wanting to create a database for a team of outbound callers. what I'd like is to be able to have a client list with a phone number that is "click to dial". We use MS teams for outbound calls so all I want is to click on the phone number in Access and have it populate in the dial pad on Teams. I've done this in excel but I'm struggling to find info on how to achieve the same thing in access.

In excel I used `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("TEL:",A1))` to turn a number into a hyperlink. the first time it is clicked on a helpful box appears asking what program I would like to use, I click teams and then subsequent clicks automatically populate the "A1" number into teams.

I've attempted to use the "phone" button in access, but this seems to want to use a "modem".
I've also tried to use the hyperlink data type to turn the number into a hyperlink. but when I click the hyperlink it tries to treat the number as a web address and does not give me the option of how what program to use like the excel formula above.

I hope that makes sense and thank you in advance.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to show what you have that works in Excel, and what you have tried so far in Access that doesn't work.

Comment: I've added an edit, please let me know if it doesn't make sense, I'm as new to stackoverflow as I am to access. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you simply need to ask Windows to run the `tel:` protocol with a number you provide. In the most simple version, something like this:

```
Sub DialNumber(sNumber As String)
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open "tel:" & sNumber
End Sub
```

This is like pasting "tel:12345678" into Start -> Run.

If you are not sure if the `tel:` URL protocol is registered, you can check the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\URL Protocol`.

Comment: thank you for your help, I'll need to spend some more time learning how to use VBA and I'll come back to this.

Comment: that didn't take long, the button works and it's all thanks to you wonderful people. I'm sure I'll be back. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same functionality by using `Application.FollowHyperlink`:

```
Private Sub Text0_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Application.FollowHyperlink "TEL:" & Me!PhoneNumber
End Sub
```